# WebView treated like native in Appium Inspector and cannot switch to webview to find elements

Tags: appium, wkwebview, appium-ios

I am testing a hybrid iOS mobile application. The first 2 screens are native, and then after that, there is a registration flow that is a WebView, and after registration the app goes back to native.

My question is that for the WebView screens, the Appium Inspector displays it to me as if it is a native screen. It gives me xpath identifiers for it that look like native elements (but are really slow to identify in actual testing).

Further, I don’t seem to be able to interact with those screens in Appium as if they are web elements. When I try to identify them using the id of the web element, Appium says css selector is not a valid locator strategy. I have tried adding a line of code that switches to a webview if it finds one, but frankly, I don’t see any sign in the appium logs that it actually tries this (though it also does not show an error about it).

I don’t understand what is happening here and would like to.

I am using Appium 1.13.0 and 1.14.0, running an iOS app on the simulator (12.2). I am using a codebase forked from https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate.

An element looks like this in Appium Inspector:

```
<XCUIElementTypeTextField type="XCUIElementTypeTextField" value="Username" label="" enabled="true" visible="true" x="40" y="224" width="294" height="60"/>
```

and the locator that the Inspector provides me looks like this:

```
//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name="Login from mobile"]/XCUIElementTypeOther[4]/XCUIElementTypeTextField
```

But in a browser, the element looks like this:

```
<input id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
```

My capabilities look like this:

```
config.capabilities = [
    {
        // The defaults you need to have in your config
        // browserName: 'safari',
        platformName: 'iOS',
        maxInstances: 1,
        // For W3C the appium capabilities need to have an extension prefix
        // This is `appium:` for all Appium Capabilities which can be found here
        // http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/
        'appium:deviceName': 'iPhone X',
        'appium:platformVersion': '12.2',
        'appium:orientation': 'PORTRAIT',
        // `automationName` will be manatory, see
        // https://github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.13.0
        'appium:app': join(process.cwd(), './apps/AiView.app.zip'),
        'appium:automationName': 'XCUITest',
        'appium:newCommandTimeout': 240,
        'autoAcceptAlerts': true,
        'appium:noReset': false
    },
];
```

A snippet of my actual test looks like this:

```
ParticipantLanguageScreen.setLanguageButton.click();
// That line is native code
driver.switchContext(this.getCurrentContexts()[1]);
ActivateLoginScreen.usernameInput.setValue(SC_USERNAME);
// That line should be a webview, but Appium is treating it as a native view
```

This locator works:

```
SC_USERNAME_INPUT: '//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name="Login from mobile"]/XCUIElementTypeOther[4]/XCUIElementTypeTextField'
```

But this one does not:

```
SC_USERNAME_INPUT: '#username'
```

Here is a part of the appium logs:

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/30491fcf-e3c4-41bf-bad0-bbf1cc71d2f9/element
[HTTP] {"using":"accessibility id","value":"SET PARTICIPANT LANGUAGE"}
[W3C (30491fcf)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["accessibility id","SET PARTICIPANT LANGUAGE","30491fcf-e3c4-41bf-bad0-bbf1cc71d2f9"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'findElement'
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, name, class name, -ios predicate string, -ios class chain, accessibility id
[BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/1E3BE1C7-5210-49E5-B405-FEE9393DEEB8/element] with body: {"using":"accessibility id","value":"SET PARTICIPANT LANGUAGE"}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"C2030000-0000-0000-CE45-000000000000"},"sessionId":"1E3BE1C7-5210-49E5-B405-FEE9393DEEB8","status":0}
[W3C (30491fcf)] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"C2030000-0000-0000-CE45-000000000000","ELEMENT":"C2030000-0000-0000-CE45-000000000000"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/30491fcf-e3c4-41bf-bad0-bbf1cc71d2f9/element 200 104 ms - 137

[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/30491fcf-e3c4-41bf-bad0-bbf1cc71d2f9/element/C2030000-0000-0000-CE45-000000000000/click
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (30491fcf)] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[XCUITest] Executing command 'proxyReqRes'
[WD Proxy] Matched '/wd/hub/session/30491fcf-e3c4-41bf-bad0-bbf1cc71d2f9/element/C2030000-0000-0000-CE45-000000000000/click' to command name 'click'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/30491fcf-e3c4-41bf-bad0-bbf1cc71d2f9/element/C2030000-0000-0000-CE45-000000000000/click] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/1E3BE1C7-5210-49E5-B405-FEE9393DEEB8/element/C2030000-0000-0000-CE45-000000000000/click] with body: {}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"status":0,"id":"C2030000-0000-0000-CE45-000000000000","value":"","sessionId":"1E3BE1C7-5210-49E5-B405-FEE9393DEEB8"}
[WD Proxy] Replacing sessionId 1E3BE1C7-5210-49E5-B405-FEE9393DEEB8 with 30491fcf-e3c4-41bf-bad0-bbf1cc71d2f9
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/30491fcf-e3c4-41bf-bad0-bbf1cc71d2f9/element/C2030000-0000-0000-CE45-000000000000/click 200 391 ms - 118
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/30491fcf-e3c4-41bf-bad0-bbf1cc71d2f9/element
[HTTP] {"using":"css selector","value":"#username"}
[W3C (30491fcf)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["css selector","#username","30491fcf-e3c4-41bf-bad0-bbf1cc71d2f9"]
[XCUITest] Executing command 'findElement'
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, name, class name, -ios predicate string, -ios class chain, accessibility id
[W3C (30491fcf)] Encountered internal error running command: InvalidSelectorError: Locator Strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at XCUITestDriver.validateLocatorStrategy (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.js:366:13)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at XCUITestDriver.validateLocatorStrategy (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:991:11)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at XCUITestDriver.validateLocatorStrategy [as findElOrElsWithProcessing] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/commands/find.js:31:8)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at XCUITestDriver.findElOrElsWithProcessing [as findElement] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/commands/find.js:53:21)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at curCommandCancellable._bluebird.default.resolve.then (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.js:305:66)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at tryCatcher (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at Promise._settlePromise (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:611:10)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at _drainQueueStep (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:142:12)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at _drainQueue (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at Async._drainQueues (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
[W3C (30491fcf)]     at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/30491fcf-e3c4-41bf-bad0-bbf1cc71d2f9/element 400 96 ms - 2501
```

I expect the Appium Inspector to not give me element locators that are xpath and appear like native elements and I expect that my test can run with identifying web elements using id attributes.